# Can't get to GCE instance from k8s pods on the same subnet

Tags: kubernetes

I have a cluster with container range `10.101.64.0/19` on a net A and subnet SA with ranges `10.101.0.0/18`. On the same subnet, there is VM in GCE with IP `10.101.0.4` and it can be pinged just fine from within the cluster, e.g. from a node with `10.101.0.3`. However, if I go to a pod on this node which got address `10.101.67.191` (which is expected - this node assigns addresses `10.101.67.0/24` or something), I don't get meaningful answer from that VM I want to access from this pod. Using tcpdump on icmp, I can see that when I ping that VM machine from the pod, the ping gets there but I don't receive ACK in the pod. Seems like VM is just throwing it away.

Any idea how to resolve it? Some routes or firewalls? I am using the same topology in the default subnet created by kubernetes where this work but I cannot find anything relevant which could explain this (there are some routes and firewall rules which could influence it but I wasn't successful when trying to mimic them in my subnet)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a firewall issue. 
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49576066/9485673) I've already provided the solution on Stakoverflow. 
It may help to solve your case.